# Add role to a method

Tags: spring, spring-security

I use Spring Boot with Spring Security.

To create an new user, the "creating" user should be an admin.

But if the "creating" user only has the standard role...

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Long createUser(@RequestBody @Valid final UserAppDto user) {
   return userService.save(user);
}
```

...the result is that a non-admin user is able to create a new user.

In my `UserApp` class, for the role, I have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

My main application

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class Application implements SchedulingConfigurer{

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter webSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new ApplicationSecurity();
    }

}

@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use pre-post annotations on controlers. They use AOP under the hood, so they do not work on controlers unless they implement interfaces or unless you use proxy-target-class=true, which may have other drawbacks (*).

This annotations should be used on services, because service beans are generaly bound in controlers as interfaces and so the AOP machinery will work as expected.

The spring-security way for limiting access to url is via http security, not via method security.

(*) in particular, never mix class proxying and JDK proxying in same application...

Comment: ok by http security, you mean something like http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER") ? is it the same thing with @Secured and @RolesAllowed?

Comment: @robertgagnon: Yes by http security, I mean `http.authorizeRequests()...`. This one is used by the spring security filter machinery before the request hits the DispatcherServlet front controller and does not depends on AOP in opposition to the `@Secured` or pre-post annotations.